# How to install vim plugin under cygwin?

Tags: vim, cygwin, vim-plugin

I installed a cygwin on my windows machine. There isn't a .vim directory in my cygwin home directory. How to install vim plugin in this case?

By the way, what plugins are suggested for HTML/CSS/JavaScript development?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you make `.vim` directory in your homedir ant install a plugin there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have Cygwin installed on WinXP : I only had to create a .vim tree directory to make it work.

Basically, create a .vim directory in your ~/ and untar you plugins in there as recommended by khachik. It should create the appropriate subdirectories like autoload, doc, etc if your plugins are correctly packaged.

You'll also have to create a .vimrc in your ~/ if you want to configure your installation.

To work with HTML, I recommend to use the [surround plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) by Tim Pope. It is great to add/remove tags quickly.

There is a cygwin/vim related question which can answer some of your concerns here : [How do I use my .vimrc file in Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1494631/513198)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the plugin manager Vundle in cygwin.

[Get it here.](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim)

To install it you just clone it into your home diectory. But since git and cygwin will interpret the path differently you have to do:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git /cygwin64/home/USERNAME/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

Just follow the instructions. At the end you have to modify the vimrc similar to a windows install but in this case you only have to modify

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
```

to

```
set rtp+=c:/cygwin64/home/USERNAME/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/
call vundle#begin('c:/cygwin64/home/USERNAME/.vim/bundle/')
```

after that you will have all the vundle comfort in vim.

Answer (score 1):

For HTML, I suggest an unofficial [Zencoding](http://mattn.github.com/zencoding-vim/) plugin.