# How to update Vim under Cygwin

Tags: vim, cygwin

Vim behaves weirdly under Cygwin.  I follow [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494631/how-do-i-use-my-vimrc-file-in-cygwin) and realize that in my `/bin` there's only `vi.exe`, no `vim.exe`!  So I put the `.vimrc` example from [Vim Wiki](http://www.vim.wikia.com/wiki/Example_vimrc) into a `.virc` in home directory.  When I run `vi`, I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing /home/USER/.virc:
line   21:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: filetype indent plugin on
line   24:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: syntax on
line  113:
E538: No mouse support: mouse=a
```

My question is:

1. How do I update vi to avoid the above errors?
2. Is it necessary to install a `vim.exe`?  If it is, how can I do that **(under Cygwin)** ?

Thanks

Comment: 1. They're not supported in vi, so you're getting errors because they're only available in vim.
2. Yes, you'll need vim.exe for the extended support of the options in your .vimrc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go back and run the CygWin `setup.exe` again and ensure you install absolutely *everything* <sup>(a)</sup> rather than just the defaults.

Disk space is cheap, time spent trying to figure out which package various things are in <sup>(b)</sup> is not :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You do this by clicking on the "tail chasing arrows" at the top level until it says "Install" (see below image <sup>(b)</sup> for an example of the arrows, though those particular ones aren't at the top level).

---

<sup>(b)</sup> Vim is in `Editors` by the way, and it defaults to skip:

[image]