# The location of .vimrc file is not found in cygwin

Tags: vim, cygwin

I use Cygwin to work with some text files and have corrupted vim settings. While searching the solution the .vimrc file wasn't found. Where the .vimrc file may be located?

Comment: There may be already answers for your question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494631/how-do-i-use-my-vimrc-file-in-cygwin)

Answer (score 0):

the expected location of `.vimrc` is your home directory, but is can also be
missing.

It changes any default that is coming from the system vimrc that is on

```
/etc/vimrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Cygwin 3.4.6 (all defaults) and vim seems to be messed up out of the box.

When running "vi" it complains with "Failed to source defaults.vim"

Although "vim" command is not installed, when "vi" opens, it displays "VIM" version 8.2.4372.  It's installed in /usr/bin/vi.

When I downloaded and installed defaults.vim (from vim github) into my user's home directory, it still complains it cannot source it, and it also fails to load my "~/.vimrc" or even "~.virc".

My $HOME env variable is set correctly, however vi cannot find any files there.

I did find a solution however, which was to make a .vim/ folder from my home directory and move .virc and defaults.vim there.  Maybe that should have been created by default in the cygwin installation.